# Any way to see LaTeX Math in a text-based browser?

Tags: browser, latex, mathjax, mathml

I'm trying to switch at least partially to text-based web browsing. Pretty everything I want to do online is available (and the stuff that isn't, like videos, I can open in external problems) but one thing isn't: LaTeX math expressions. I read a lot of websites that revolve around math and they typically use MathJax or MathML to express mathematical notation. Is there anyway to see these in a text-based browser (besides just using w3m-img since most of these websites don't use images for math notation)? <s>Also I've been trying to build a blog of my own which will probably have some math articles and I'm wondering which way of expressing math notation, if any, would work for text-based browsers.</s>

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have a preferred text-based browser? Also, please limit your post to a single question. If you have two questions, please ask them as separate questions.

Comment: Sorry I thought they were related enough to one. I'll post a separate thread for the second question but I'll leave it on this one with a strike-through for transparency. And I use w3m compiled with image support.

Comment: They are related, but the answer to one is not the answer to the other. SuperUser is designed to be about single answers to single questions. That's why you'll get to select one answer as "The Answer" once they've come in. You can't mark two posts as answers to a single question.